# Filtering JSON table displayed in HTML using Javascript - All values disappear

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I have created a table in HTML from a JSON file which contains an index, name and price for several games. I need to allow the user to filter through the values by typing a name i.e. "Counter Strike: Global Offensive" into a search box.

The problem I am encountering now is that when I type anything into the search bar the table disappears entirely. I have been trying different solutions for some time now and can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. The index, name and price headings also disappear.

The following is my Javascript, first the function for populating the table, followed by the one which is meant to be filtering the table.

```js
$.getJSON("http:.../steamcrawler.json",
    function (data) {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].index + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Game + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Price + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
    });

    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("data");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
         if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
           tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name"> <table id="data"></table>
```

I am not getting any error messages before or after typing in the search box. The complete table is displayed before typing, and disappears entirely as soon as I type a character into the bar. The following is the HTML for the table and the search bar.

Any help would be appreciated, i'm quite new to Javascript and different aspects of this project have been giving me headaches for weeks!

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The first td of your tr (corresponding to the zeroth td in your code) contains the "index".  That is currently the text you are searching in to find what the user typed.  To me it seems like you want to search in the game td, which is `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];`

Comment: As soon as I read your first sentence I immediately realized my mistake. Thank you, I knew it was going to be something dumb like that!!